# Button text hidden iOS9 UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiappearance

I have already tried a couple of approach while resolving this issue. Something new in iOS9.
As soon as I touch the button control on UIAcitivityView and drag it away the text becomes available. I am not pretty much sure what it is.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UIActivityViewController class], nil]
         setTintColor:[UIColor
                       colorWithHexString:@"F00000"]]
```

Did anyone face the similar problem.
I am also attaching an image along to better analyze the problem.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UIActivityViewController class], nil]
         setTintColor:[UIColor colorName]]
```

This does not work for the UIActivityViewController as well as UIAlertView in iOS9. Have to do it manually on each view controller.

```
UIActivityViewController *activity = [...];
[activity.view setTint:[UIColor colorName]];
```